# problem in Google Play Campaign Attribution implementation

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-analytics-campaign-builder

My app is in beta testing and I want to add the google campaigns for my app to track the traffic and tried one of the method **Google Play Campaign Attribution**. I have followed the steps in this link
[google campaign link](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/campaigns#general-campaigns)
and added the required code in **manifest.xml** and after that tried to broadcast the intent from command line with **adb shell** using command

> am broadcast -a com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER -n "com.packagename/com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingReceiver" --es "referrer" "utm_source=google&utm_medium=link&utm_term=install_refer&utm_content=install_refer&utm_campaign=install_refer"

and then i got the result

> Broadcasting: Intent { act=com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER flg=0x400000 cmp=com.packagename/com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingReceiver (has extras) } Broadcast completed: result=0

but when i opened again the app there is not any analytics reports are sent.
I have checked the **Acquisition reports** but not found any.

Do i also have to do the  **General Campaign & Traffic Source Attribution** step to work it on that page.
What have i missed ?.

Answer (score 0):

The issues is actually the reports are sending to google but i am not able to see the google analytics report in the acquisition reports dashboard immediately because as i am using the free account. If i have the premium version of google analytics i can live track the reports.